# Protractor: Can you delay the WebElement.sendKeys() globally onPrepare?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, protractor, automated-tests

I am runing protractor on a slow machine and I need protractor to slow down each key press and each action. The action part is done, but how can I do the keyPress part?

I have a local solution with is:

```
function delay(el, value, newDelay) {
    for (var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
        browser.sleep(newDelay || browser.params.delay);
        el.sendKeys(value[i]);
    }
}
```

In onPrepare I was able to slow down each action with:

```
browser.driver.controlFlow().execute = function () {
    var args = arguments;

    if (arguments[1] === "WebElement.sendKeys()")
        debugger;

    origFn.call(browser.driver.controlFlow(), function () {
        return protractor.promise.delayed(100);
    });

    return origFn.apply(browser.driver.controlFlow(), args);
};
```

but I don't know how to slow down the sendKeys, I belive I have to do something where I placed the debugger, but what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aparenty, the only solution I found, was to try and send at first the entire string and if it fails, send the keys one by one, and check again, so my code is something like this:

```
el.getAttribute('value').then(function (insertedValue) {
    if (insertedValue !== value) {
        el.clear().then(function () {
            el.sendKeys(protractor.Key.END);
            for (var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
                browser.sleep(100);
                el.sendKeys(value[i]);
                el.sendKeys(protractor.Key.END);
            }
            if (tryNo < 1) {
                el.getAttribute('value').then(function (insertedValue) {
                    if (insertedValue !== value) {
                        .......................
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```